# browsers with IRC-support: which one supports client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, client-side, irc

Some browsers like Opera have support for IRC so there's no need to have a separate IRC-client like MIRC.

Is there a browser that supports client-side JavaScript that catches incoming messages and allows making use of it? I'm asking this because as far as I know they usually catch enhance HTML/XML-events.

Currently I'd be trying to catch the regular messages and none of the controlling messages like "user has joined", "user has left" and such.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a firefox plugin! If there isn't then the answer is write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera's IRC client is not scriptable at all (besides what it barely works)

ChatZilla is. Moreover, it was written in JavaScript - https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/chatzilla/

Comment: I don't know about "barely". The chatting itself seems to work through the channel and private window. I have no idea about how the other things work with Opera, like DCC. However, I agree that it's not that full-featured. -- Other than that, our discussion continued and we'll probably be using some free IRC-client, ChatZilla is on that list, too.

Comment: @sjngm, sorry, i have no idea about which discussion you mentioning. Re: Opera - chatting works ok, idling doesnt (drops connection), various other annoyances (eg: own nick charset broken - http://al.freehostia.com/opera/opera_ballet.gif)

Comment: (just checked, both bug persists) Problem is - Opera developers made really draft client and seems to be satisfied with it.